# How to separate rows having only characters from alphanumeric as IDs in a Pyspark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pyspark dataframe having ID column, which has both characters only and alphanumeric combination as identifiers.

I want to remove character only Ids from my dataFrame.

```
predictions.select('client_id', 'probability').show(1000,False)

|client_id|probability
|RAJU     |[0.9998043367405032,1.9566325949689167E-4]|
|JMS      |[0.9998043367405032,1.9566325949689167E-4]|
|ATON     |[0.9998043367405032,1.9566325949689167E-4]|
|VK1234   |[0.9998043367405032,1.9566325949689167E-4]|
|KSC      |[0.9998043367405032,1.9566325949689167E-4]|
|K122229  |[0.9998043367405032,1.9566325949689167E-4]|
```

I have tried

```
predictions2 = predictions.filter(~predictions['client_id'].rlike('[a-zA-Z]'))
```

But I am getting empty rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
predictions.filter(~predictions['client_id'].rlike('^[a-zA-Z]+$'))
```

Your regex will remove any rows with alphabets, even if there are numbers in the rows. You need to make sure that the rows ONLY contains characters, and the way to do this is to specify the beginning and end of string, `^` and `$`. `+` is also needed to specify that there are 1 or more alphabets in the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check the negation: "*`client_id` contains at least one digit*":

```
predictions2 = predictions.filter(predictions["client_id"].rlike(r"\d"))

predictions2.show(truncate=False)  
#+---------+-------------------------------------------+
#|client_id|probability                                |
#+---------+-------------------------------------------+
#|VK1234   |[0.9998043367405032, 1.9566325949689167E-4]|
#|K122229  |[0.9998043367405032, 1.9566325949689167E-4]|
#+---------+-------------------------------------------+
```